# How to show on a web page how many kilobytes was already downloaded by a browser in order to show this page?

Tags: javascript

How to show on a web page how many kilobytes was already downloaded by a browser in order to show this page using, for example, javascript circular progress bar with running numbers? For example, I have a page with a large Silverlight application. The Silverlight default splash screen progressbar displays 0% constantly somehow, but after that the application works properly. However, I know in advance, that my site is 5MB including the Silverlight application and I want to show progress to a user in the form "2.7MB loaded from 5MB".

Comment: I think the Silverlight application should be in charge of saying how far it's loaded.

Comment: Such information is displayed by the browser in its status or somewhere, but not by the page that is currently downloaded. However, what you maybe could show is how much of the page source code is currently parsed.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done: you don't have access to page loading information.